# Checking simple char device read/write functions in LINUX

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am new to linux kernel programming. I wrote a simple kernel module and char device. I  defined the open(), release(), read() and write() methods of device. I initialize my module with insmod and removed it with rmmod and all works correct. Now I want to check my read() write() methods of the device. Could you please tell me how to write a user program which should implement the read/write methods of my char device ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first test you can do when you have a character device and you want to check your implementation of `read` and `write` syscalls is to:

- write with the `echo` shell command: `echo 42 > /dev/char_device`
- read with the `cat` command or a specified number of bytes with the `head` command (or with `dd`) and convert to hexadecimal with `od -x` if necessary: `head -8 /dev/char_device | od -x`

Now to write a program in C, just use `fopen` to open the file and use `fread` and `fwrite` to read and write data; you can also use `read` and `write` syscalls, but `fread` and `fwrite` are standard C library functions that wrap `read` and `write`.

Comment: how to select the size and the address?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a device file in `/dev` if it's not already automatically created. Then you can write a program that opens and reads from/writes to that file.